# Setting "User-Agent" parameters for URLConnection for querying Google from a Java application

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, google-search

I am trying to get the results back from a Google query, in Java as follows:

```
String urlquery = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&tbm=nws&q=apples&oq=apples";
URL url = new URL(urlquery);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
URLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5");
```

But, I don't know how to set the "User-Agent" parameters above. From where do I get the values for my system? I just copied these values from some code I found online.

My system configuration is as follows:
Mac OSX 10.8.3
Intel i7
Safari 6.0.3(8536.28.10)

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to know what to set your user agent to so you can mimic the response that browser will get you can use this site.

http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: The funny thing is... I saw your referral from that site, which lead me here ;)

Answer (score 4):

The steps blow can help you to get the "User-Agent":

1. open the chrome , press the F12.
2. enter any available web site , then press Enter.
3. click the "NetWork" on DevTools, and click the web site that entered just right.
4. so you can find the "User-Agent", just like the picture below.
   [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9k7Y.png)